# Is there a common set of modules for user-defining-quantum-gate for QISKit

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am wondering if there exists a common library or a set of modules for user-defining-quantum-gate for QISKit.

If it does, could you tell me?

By referring to [Define Quantum Gates](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx/community/question?questionId=5b3ba83d77993f003c6952dd) and [How to define user's quantum gates?](https://quantumexperience.ng.bluemix.net/qx/community/question?questionId=5ae975660f020500399ed22d&answerId=5ae975760f020500399ee66e), I have created 6 modules for IBM Q simulator such as CZ gate and CCZ gate ([uploaded here](https://github.com/bick-jp/ibmq/tree/master/grovers_algorithm/original_gate_test/original_gate)) since they were not built in [QISKit standard gates](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/tree/master/qiskit/extensions/standard).

However, since the gates such as CZ gate and CCZ gate seems pretty common to use, I am wondering if anybody already opens their gates to the public.

Answer (score 2):

For the moment, there is no publicly available repository of custom gates to my knowledge.

If you want I have defined some for my own use. You can find the implementation [here](https://github.com/nelimee/quantum-tools/tree/master/gates) but:

- The "gates" implemented are more algorithms than gates.
- If you plan to re-use some of the gates, take a look at the license.

Be also aware of the fact that the gate hierarchy will probably change in a near future (see [#316](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/316), [#476](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/476), [#591](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/591)). Even if the changes should be backward compatible, we don't know how the `CompositeGate` class will be changed at the moment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information! I will keep in mind the possible change of CompositeGate. Meanwhile, I will create some gates such as CZ, CCZ, CCCX by myself and open them to the public.